# Error SQL Command Vb6: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6, multi-query

I am programming in VB6. However, I met a problem with execute SQL query in VB6. I try to solve it by searching and learning in Internet, but, I also cannot. Help me please, thank you.

This is my code:

```
SqlText = "delete from Student where Subject in (SELECT Subject FROM MarkTable where Xcode = ? )"
Set dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI = New ADODB.Command
With dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI
        .ActiveConnection = dbCon
        .CommandText = SqlText
        .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With
```

Next

```
dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI.Parameters(0) = pIX
dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI.Execute
```

When I run program, error is displayed in line: `dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI.Parameters(0) = pIX` 
and I recevied message:

> Syntax error or access violation

I think that I have problem when I try to run Delete query and Select query at the same time. However, I also have not how to solve it.
Please help me,

Thank you so much,

Comment: ur table names and column names are in other language pls make it in english

Comment: ry this `dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI.Parameters.Append dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI.CreateParameter("a name for parameter", parameter_data_type, adParamInput,Size,pIX)`

Comment: is it working as per above comment

Comment: Glad to hear it helped..put it as answer..mark it as solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI.Parameters(0) = pIX
```

TO

```
 dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI.Parameters.Append 
 dbCmdDelJUUCHUUMESAI.CreateParameter("a name for parameter",
 parameter_data_type, adParamInput,Size,pIX)
```